# SQL - Why is my INSERT query dying?

Tags: php, mysql, die

```
echo "</br></br></br>" . $sql;
mysql_query($sql) or die("Entry not added to database.");
```

is spitting out:

```
INSERT INTO potentials (id, firstname, lastname, age, email, phone, twitter, timeofday, dayofweek, address, city, state, zip, joindate, parentname, parentnumber) VALUES (null, 'Rick', 'Bross', '14', 'rbross3@gmail.com', '8164896991', '@rick_bross', 'After 5:30PM', 'Weekdays', '1234 Cooper', 'Raymore', 'MO', '64130', '2013-04-09 20:10:06', 'Rick Bross II', '1234123412')Entry not added to database.
```

Why isn't it being inserted correctly? Can I check if one of the strings isnt fitting into my database column (type type char error or something)?

Comment: did you connect correctly the database before querying it ? `mysql_connect`.. Note : you shoudl use mysqli instead of mysql functions

Comment: Don't see anything wrong with your sql.  Can you supply your table structure?

Comment: Yeah, I was fine before I added the parentname, parentphone fields into the db and added them to the query. What is the best way for me to show you the structure?

Comment: Use explain -- explain potentials;

Comment: <<Insert standard comment about trying to avoid `mysql_` functions (switch to mysqli or pdo) here>>

Comment: Change `die("Entry not added to database.")` to `die(mysql_error())` and post the message here. It will be helpful for everyone.

Comment: Yeah, fembb posted it. It led me straight to my problems. I forgot to create one or two columns within the table. DOH!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

try msql_error() function. It is globally show every error happens with your sql execution